# Why does $V=\frac{1}{3}Bh$ hold for any pyramid?

Tags: geometry, volume

For some personal math study I was looking at the derivation for the general pyramid volume formula ($V=\frac{1}{3}Bh$). I understand where this comes from in the case of a square-based pyramid, but I do not understand why it holds for any other pyramid with a regular polygon base. I did the square-base derivation using integration. How would I set up the integral for some general regular polygon (ex. Triangle, Octagon, etc.). Again, this isn’t for anything in particular, just an exercise I am choosing to do for fun.

Comment: [Cavalieri's Principle](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/hs-geo-solids/xff63fac4:hs-geo-cavalieri-s-principle/a/cavalieri-s-principle-in-3d), which is a precursor to Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: That works for any base, because any other section parallel to the base is similar to it. Hence you can repeat the same reasoning as for a square base.